# POI 5.0.0, xmlbeans-5.0.1, xlsx-streamer-2.2.0 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.getEntryAt(I)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I upgraded POI from 4.1.1 to 5.0.0, xmlbeans from 3.0.2 to 5.0.1, xlsx-streamer-2.2.0, After upgrading poi getting below error.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.getEntryAt(I)Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTRst;

The issue is coming over iterating com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingSheet

Even I tried downgrading xmlbeans to 3.0.1 and 3.0.2 but no luck.

Comment: Several potential issues come to my mind, like duplicated POI jars, like the old ooxml-schemas - see [component page](http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html) - or maybe incompatible xlsx-streamer. To identify the culprit, I would use a packager manager (maven or gradle) and only reference the poi-ooxml artifact. exclude batik to minimize the size. then create a dummy xssfworkbook for a test. then check which conflicting dependencies xlsx-streamer brings in and exclude those.

Comment: this is caused by https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/issues/227 - https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader does not support POI 5 - I have a fork https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader/ that does support POI 5

Comment: yes @PJFanning,  Thank you for the confirmation, Now I am using pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader(https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) to provide support to the POI-5.0.0 version instead of using monitorjbl xlsx-streamer  
, monitorjbl xlsx-streamer 2.2.0(https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader) is not support to POI-5.0.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

monitorjbl xlsx-streamer 2.2.0 doesn't support apache poi 5.0.0.need to be replaced with https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader dependency.